# MySQL query optimization and EXPLAIN for a noob

Tags: sql, mysql, database, query-optimization

I've been working with databases for a long time but I'm new to query optimization. I have the following query (some of it code-generated):

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(gi.start_time, '') start_time,
COALESCE(b.name, '') bank,
COALESCE(a.id, '') account_id,
COALESCE(a.account_number, '') account_number,
COALESCE(at.code, '') account_type,
COALESCE(a.open_date, '') open_date,
COALESCE(a.interest_rate, '') interest_rate,
COALESCE(a.maturity_date, '') maturity_date,
COALESCE(a.opening_balance, '') opening_balance,
COALESCE(a.has_e_statement, '') has_e_statement,
COALESCE(a.has_bill_pay, '') has_bill_pay,
COALESCE(a.has_overdraft_protection, '') has_overdraft_protection,
COALESCE(a.balance, '') balance,
COALESCE(a.business_or_personal, '') business_or_personal,
COALESCE(a.cumulative_balance, '') cumulative_balance,
COALESCE(c.customer_number, '') customer_number,
COALESCE(c.social_security_number, '') social_security_number,
COALESCE(c.name, '') customer_name,
COALESCE(c.phone, '') phone,
COALESCE(c.deceased, '') deceased,
COALESCE(c.do_not_mail, '') do_not_mail,
COALESCE(cdob.date_of_birth, '') date_of_birth,
COALESCE(ad.line1, '') line1,
COALESCE(ad.line2, '') line2,
COALESCE(ad.city, '') city,
COALESCE(s.name, '') state,
COALESCE(ad.zip, '') zip,
COALESCE(o.officer_number, '') officer_number,
COALESCE(o.name, '') officer_name,
COALESCE(po.line1, '') po_box,
COALESCE(po.city, '') po_city,
COALESCE(po_state.name, '') po_state,
COALESCE(po.zip, '') zip,
COALESCE(br.number, '') branch_number,
COALESCE(cd_type.code, '') cd_type,
COALESCE(mp.product_number, '') macatawa_product_number,
COALESCE(mp.product_name, '') macatawa_product_name,
COALESCE(pt.name, '') macatawa_product_type,
COALESCE(hhsc.name, '') harte_hanks_service_category,
COALESCE(mp.hoh_hierarchy, '') hoh_hierarchy,
COALESCE(cft.name, '') core_file_type,
COALESCE(oa.line1, '') original_address_line1,
COALESCE(oa.line2, '') original_address_line2,
COALESCE(uc.code, '') use_class
            FROM account a
            JOIN customer c ON a.customer_id = c.id
            JOIN officer o ON a.officer_id = o.id
            JOIN account_address aa ON aa.account_id = a.id
       LEFT JOIN account_po_box apb ON apb.account_id = a.id                
            JOIN address ad ON aa.address_id = ad.id
            JOIN original_address oa ON oa.address_id = ad.id
       LEFT JOIN address po ON apb.address_id = po.id
            JOIN state s ON s.id = ad.state_id
       LEFT JOIN state po_state ON po_state.id = po.state_id
       LEFT JOIN branch br ON a.branch_id = br.id
            JOIN account_import ai ON a.account_import_id = ai.id
            JOIN generic_import gi ON gi.id = ai.generic_import_id
            JOIN import_bundle ib ON gi.import_bundle_id = ib.id
            JOIN bank b ON b.id = ib.bank_id
       LEFT JOIN customer_date_of_birth cdob ON cdob.customer_id = c.id
       LEFT JOIN cd_type ON a.cd_type_id = cd_type.id
       LEFT JOIN account_macatawa_product amp ON amp.account_id = a.id
       LEFT JOIN macatawa_product mp ON mp.id = amp.macatawa_product_id
       LEFT JOIN product_type pt ON pt.id = mp.product_type_id
       LEFT JOIN harte_hanks_service_category hhsc
            ON hhsc.id = mp.harte_hanks_service_category_id
       LEFT JOIN core_file_type cft ON cft.id = mp.core_file_type_id
       LEFT JOIN use_class uc ON a.use_class_id = uc.id
       LEFT JOIN account_type at ON a.account_type_id = at.id

         WHERE 1
           AND gi.active = 1
           AND b.id = 8 AND ib.is_finished = 1

        ORDER BY a.id
           LIMIT 10
```

And it's pretty slow. On my dev server it takes about a minute to run and on my production server, where there's more data, I can't get it to even finish. Here's what an `EXPLAIN` looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR6lq.png

I know the basics of `EXPLAIN`. I know that it's good that I have something other than `NULL` for everything under `key`. But I don't know, overall, how much room for improvement my query has. I do know that `Using temporary; Using filesort` under `Extra` is bad, but I have no idea what to do about it.

Comment: do you have indexes on the tables you are joining?

Comment: I have indexes on some of the columns on most of the tables I'm joining.

Comment: @jason swett - the relevant columns in this query are the ones that you join on.  see my answer below.

Comment: Is the EXPLAIN result coming from the production server or the dev server?

Comment: Can you try the `EXPLAIN` on the production server, after an `ANALYZE TABLE` on all involved tables? The proper number of rows could lead to a very different execution path, I guess...

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` I posted is from the dev server. I'll post the production one after I get done adding these indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have indexes on most of your `JOIN` fields.  Make sure **every** field  that you use as a `JOIN` key has an index on both tables.

With 23 joins and what looks like only 2 relevant indexes, poor performance can be expected.

With no index to reference, the query engine is checking every row in both tables to compare them, which is obviously very inefficient.

**edit:**

For example, in your query you have

`JOIN customer c ON a.customer_id = c.id`

Make sure you have an index on `a.customer_id` **AND** `customer.id`.  Having an index on both tables (on the `JOIN`ed fields) will exponentially speed up the query.

Comment: Good, so there's apparently a lot of room for improvement. When you say "make sure every field...has an index on both tables", what exactly do you mean by index? In my limited knowledge, an index is something you add to a column, not to a table.

Comment: @Jason - it is on a column.  I'll edit the answer for details.

Comment: Here's a guess: would I add an index to, say, `customer.id` and `account.customer_id`? And then just apply that same idea everywhere?

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. Just to make sure I'm doing it right before I go through and make all these changes, I think I would do `create index index_customer_id on customer (id) using btree` and `create index index_account_customer_id on account (customer_id) using btree`. Is that the right idea?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @JNK mentioned in his answer about ensuring you have indexes, I have restructured your query and added the "STRAIGHT_JOIN" clause at the top which tells the optimizer to do the query in the order the tables are presented to it.

Since your query is based on the generic import, to import bundle to bank, I've moved THOSE to the front of the list... The where will pre-qualify THOSE records first instead of looking at all accounts that may never be part of the result.  So, the join is now reversed from the generic import back to the account following the same relationships you started with.

I've also associated the respective JOIN / ON conditions directly under the table they were joining against for readability and following table relationships.  I've also made it so the ON clause has Table1.ID = JoinedTable.ID... although some reversed and otherwise no big deal, knowing how something is based on the join INTO the other just allows easier readability.

So, ensure respective tables have indexes on whatever key column is the join, and from this sample query, make sure your GI table (alias) has an index on "Active", and your IB (alias) has an index on Is_Finished.

Lastly, your WHERE clause had WHERE 1 AND... no purpose of the "1", so I stripped that out.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN DISTINCT 
      COALESCE(gi.start_time, '') start_time, 
      COALESCE(b.name, '') bank, 
      COALESCE(a.id, '') account_id, 
      COALESCE(a.account_number, '') account_number, 
      COALESCE(at.code, '') account_type, 
      COALESCE(a.open_date, '') open_date, 
      COALESCE(a.interest_rate, '') interest_rate, 
      COALESCE(a.maturity_date, '') maturity_date, 
      COALESCE(a.opening_balance, '') opening_balance, 
      COALESCE(a.has_e_statement, '') has_e_statement, 
      COALESCE(a.has_bill_pay, '') has_bill_pay, 
      COALESCE(a.has_overdraft_protection, '') has_overdraft_protection, 
      COALESCE(a.balance, '') balance, 
      COALESCE(a.business_or_personal, '') business_or_personal, 
      COALESCE(a.cumulative_balance, '') cumulative_balance, 
      COALESCE(c.customer_number, '') customer_number, 
      COALESCE(c.social_security_number, '') social_security_number, 
      COALESCE(c.name, '') customer_name, 
      COALESCE(c.phone, '') phone, 
      COALESCE(c.deceased, '') deceased, 
      COALESCE(c.do_not_mail, '') do_not_mail, 
      COALESCE(cdob.date_of_birth, '') date_of_birth, 
      COALESCE(ad.line1, '') line1, 
      COALESCE(ad.line2, '') line2, 
      COALESCE(ad.city, '') city, 
      COALESCE(s.name, '') state, 
      COALESCE(ad.zip, '') zip, 
      COALESCE(o.officer_number, '') officer_number, 
      COALESCE(o.name, '') officer_name, 
      COALESCE(po.line1, '') po_box, 
      COALESCE(po.city, '') po_city, 
      COALESCE(po_state.name, '') po_state, 
      COALESCE(po.zip, '') zip, 
      COALESCE(br.number, '') branch_number, 
      COALESCE(cd_type.code, '') cd_type, 
      COALESCE(mp.product_number, '') macatawa_product_number, 
      COALESCE(mp.product_name, '') macatawa_product_name, 
      COALESCE(pt.name, '') macatawa_product_type, 
      COALESCE(hhsc.name, '') harte_hanks_service_category, 
      COALESCE(mp.hoh_hierarchy, '') hoh_hierarchy, 
      COALESCE(cft.name, '') core_file_type, 
      COALESCE(oa.line1, '') original_address_line1, 
      COALESCE(oa.line2, '') original_address_line2, 
      COALESCE(uc.code, '') use_class             
   FROM 
      generic_import gi 
         JOIN import_bundle ib 
            ON gi.import_bundle_id = ib.id
            JOIN bank b 
               ON ib.bank_id = b.id 
         JOIN account_import ai 
            ON gi.id = ai.generic_import_id
         JOIN  account a
            ON ai.id = a.account_import_id
            JOIN customer c 
               ON a.customer_id = c.id
               LEFT JOIN customer_date_of_birth cdob 
                  ON c.id = cdob.customer_id
            JOIN officer o 
               ON a.officer_id = o.id
            LEFT JOIN branch br 
               ON a.branch_id = br.id
            LEFT JOIN cd_type 
               ON a.cd_type_id = cd_type.id
            LEFT JOIN account_macatawa_product amp 
               ON a.id = amp.account_id
               LEFT JOIN macatawa_product mp 
                  ON amp.macatawa_product_id = mp.id
                  LEFT JOIN product_type pt 
                     ON mp.product_type_id = pt.id
                  LEFT JOIN harte_hanks_service_category hhsc 
                     ON mp.harte_hanks_service_category_id = hhsc.id
                  LEFT JOIN core_file_type cft 
                     ON mp.core_file_type_id = cft.id
            LEFT JOIN use_class uc 
               ON a.use_class_id = uc.id
            LEFT JOIN account_type at 
               ON a.account_type_id = at.id
            JOIN account_address aa 
               ON a.id = aa.account_id 
               JOIN address ad 
                  ON aa.address_id = ad.id 
                  JOIN original_address oa 
                     ON ad.id = oa.address_id
                  JOIN state s 
                     ON ad.state_id = s.id 
            LEFT JOIN account_po_box apb 
               ON a.id = apb.account_id 
               LEFT JOIN address po 
                  ON apb.address_id = po.id
                  LEFT JOIN state po_state 
                     ON po.state_id = po_state.id
      WHERE 
              gi.active = 1
          AND ib.is_finished = 1
          AND b.id = 8 
      ORDER BY 
          a.id
       LIMIT 
          10
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this. One thing I'm confused on: if I try to run the query it complains that "ai" is not a unique alias, which is true since you have `JOIN account_import ai` twice, but I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: @Jason Swett, revised, I took out the second instance... it was duplicated from when I reversed the primary query elements... Try this one.