# How to make ORDER BY in JOIN query faster? Nothing I have tried has worked

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by, query-optimization

I have the following JOIN query:

```
SELECT
    table1.*, 
    table2.*
FROM 
    Table1 AS table1 
LEFT JOIN 
    Table2 AS table2 
USING 
    (col1)
LEFT JOIN 
    Table3 as table3 
USING 
    (col1) 
WHERE 
    3963.191 * 
    ACOS(
    (SIN(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * SIN(PI() * table3.latitude / 180)) 
    +
    (COS(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * COS(PI() * table3.latitude / 180) * COS(PI() * table3.longitude / 180 - PI() * 37.1092162 / 180))
    ) <= 10 
AND 
    table1.col1 != '1' 
AND 
    table1.col2 LIKE 'A' 
AND 
    (table1.col3 LIKE 'X' OR table1.col3 LIKE 'X-Y') 
AND 
    (table2.col4 = 'Y' OR table2.col5 = 'Y') 


// Data Types of all columns in the query:
// col1: int(11)
// col2: char(1)
// col3: varchar(3)
// col4: char(1)
// col5: char(1)
// col6: int(11)
// latitude: varchar(25)
// longitude: varchar(25)

// All 3 tables (table1, table2, and table3) are `MyISAM`.
```

It executes in under **0.15 seconds**.

However, if I simply add:

```
ORDER BY 
    table1.col6 DESC
```

It executes in over **3 seconds**.

**All** columns in the query are **indexed**, including the `table1.col6` used in the `ORDER BY`.

Here are the results of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` **WITHOUT** `ORDER BY`:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  table1  ALL PRIMARY,col2,col3   NULL    NULL    NULL    140101  72.61   Using where
1   SIMPLE  table2  eq_ref  PRIMARY,col4,col5   PRIMARY 4   table1.col1 1   100 Using where
1   SIMPLE  table3  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   table1.col1 1   100 Using where
```

And here are the results of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` **WITH** `ORDER BY`:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  table1  ALL PRIMARY,col2,col3   NULL    NULL    NULL    140101  72.61   Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  table2  eq_ref  PRIMARY,col4,col5   PRIMARY 4   table1.col1 1   100 Using where
1   SIMPLE  table3  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   table1.col1 1   100 Using where
```

What's strange is that I use `ORDER BY DESC` in several other queries on this site, and it doesn't slow it down anywhere near as much as with this particular query. There is something specific to this query that is causing it to significantly slow down with the `ORDER BY`.

I also did an `ANALYZE TABLE` on all 3 tables, and they all reported `OK`. I then replaced every `LIKE` in the query with `=` and it actually made the query WITHOUT the `ORDER BY` go from **0.2 seconds** to **3 seconds**. In other words, replacing `LIKE` with `=` makes the original query take *just as long* as adding `ORDER BY`! How is that possible, considering `LIKE` does more work than `=`? Perhaps therein lies the clue as to why the `ORDER BY` takes so long?

**HERE'S WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR (UNSUCCESSFULLY):**

1) Instead of `SELECT table1.*, table2.*`, I tried just `SELECT table1.col1` and it *still* took over **3 seconds** to complete.

2) I tried adding a **composite index** on `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, and `col6` in `Table1`, but it did not improve the execution speed.

3) I tried [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884661/slow-query-when-using-order-by) of making the query as a sub-query and then wrapping the `ORDER BY` outside it at the end, but it did not improve the execution speed.

4) I tried the following version of the query, but it did NOT improve anything, and actually made the query take over **3 seconds** WITHOUT even the `ORDER BY` added to it (perhaps that provides yet another clue):

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      T1.*, 
      T2.*
   FROM 
      Table1 AS T1
         JOIN Table2 AS T2
            ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
            AND ( T2.Col4 = 'Y' OR T2.Col5 = 'Y' )
         JOIN Table3 as T3
            ON T1.Col1 = T3.Col1
            AND 3963.191 
               * ACOS(  (SIN(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * SIN(PI() * T3.latitude / 180)) 
                                + (  COS(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * COS(PI() * T3.latitude / 180) 
                                   * COS(PI() * table3.longitude / 180 - PI() * 37.1092162 / 180)
                        )   
                     ) <= 10 
   WHERE
          T1.Col2 LIKE 'A'
      AND ( T1.col3 LIKE 'X' OR T1.col3 LIKE 'X-Y') 
      AND T1.Col1 != '1'
   ORDER BY
      T1.Col6

// With the following composite indexes:
// On Table 1, index on ( Col2, Col3, Col1, Col6 )
// On Table 2, index on ( Col1, Col4, Col5 )

// Remember, all individual columns are already indexed.
```

...

**How can I get this stubborn query to run fast WITH the `ORDER BY`?**  Or is that just not possible?

---

**EDIT:**

Results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all 3 Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table1` (
 `col1` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `col100` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `col101` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `col102` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `col103` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '00000000',
 `col104` date NOT NULL,
 `col105` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
 `col106` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `col107` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col108` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'No',
 `col109` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col2` enum('A','B') COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `col3` enum('A','B','A-B') COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `col110` decimal(10,7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000',
 `col111` decimal(10,7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000000',
 `col112` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'N',
 `col113` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'N',
 `col114` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `col115` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `col117` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `col118` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `col119` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 `col120` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `col121` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `col122` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `col123` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
 `col124` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `col125` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `col126` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `col127` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
 `col128` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `col129` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `col130` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
 `col131` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `col132` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `col133` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `col134` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `col135` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `col136` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `col137` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `col138` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `col139` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `col140` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `col141` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `col142` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `col143` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `col144` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `col145` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`col1`),
 KEY `col2` (`col2`),
 KEY `col3` (`col3`),
 KEY `CompositeIndex0` (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col6`),
 KEY `CompositeIndex1` (`col2`,`col3`,`col1`,`col6`),
 KEY `idx01` (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`)
 [19 other indexes that do not involve col1, col2, col3, or col6...]
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=160640 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

//*******************************************************//

CREATE TABLE `Table2` (
 `col1` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `col201` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col202` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col203` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col204` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col205` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col206` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col207` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col208` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col209` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col210` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col211` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col212` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col213` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col214` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col215` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col216` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col217` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col218` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col219` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col220` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col221` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col222` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col223` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col224` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT ‘Blah’,
 `col225` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `col4` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'A',
 `col226` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'A',
 `col227` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col228` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `col229` text COLLATE utf8_bin,
 `col5` char(1) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'A',
 `col230` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'Blah',
 `col231` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `col232` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `col233` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`col1`),
 KEY `col4` (`col4`),
 KEY `col5` (`col5`),
 KEY `CompositeIndex1` (`col1`,`col4`,`col5`),
 [4 other indexes not involving col1, col4, col5...]
 FULLTEXT KEY `col220` (`col220`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

//*******************************************************//

CREATE TABLE `Table3` (
 `col1` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `col300` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `latitude` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `longitude` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `col301` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `static2` float(18,16) DEFAULT '0.0000000000000000',
 `static3` float(18,16) DEFAULT '0.0000000000000000',
 PRIMARY KEY (`col1`),
 KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
 KEY `longitude` (`longitude`),
 KEY `static2` (`static2`),
 KEY `static3` (`static3`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Below is my **MySQL Configuration File**.  Among other things, please notice how the `sort-buffer-size` is set to `1M`.  According to [this](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/more-on-understanding-sort_buffer_size-2010-05-10/), it should not be set above `256K` or it can actually slow things down by "37x".  **Could that be part of the problem?**

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.

[mysqld]

open-files-limit                = 20000

thread-cache-size               = 16
table-open-cache                = 2048
table-definition-cache          = 512

query-cache-type                = 1
query-cache-size                = 32M
query-cache-limit               = 1M

sort-buffer-size                = 1M
read-buffer-size                = 1M
read-rnd-buffer-size            = 8M
join-buffer-size                = 1M

tmp-table-size                  = 64M 
max-heap-table-size             = 64M

back-log                        = 100
max-connections                 = 200
max-connect-errors              = 10000
max-allowed-packet              = 16M
interactive-timeout             = 600
wait-timeout                    = 180
net_read_timeout        = 30
net_write_timeout       = 30

back_log            = 128

myisam-sort-buffer-size         = 128M

innodb-buffer-pool-size         = 320M
innodb-log-buffer-size          = 4M

innodb-log-file-size           = 128M
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2

innodb-file-per-table           = 1

[mysqldump]
max-allowed-packet      = 16M
```

On a different matter, here are the RESULTS OF `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` ON LATEST QUERY FROM IVAN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  T1  ref PRIMARY,col2,col3,col1,CompositeIndex1,idx01    CompositeIndex1 2   const   92333   Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  T3  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   T1.col1 1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  T2  eq_ref  PRIMARY,CompositeIndex1,idx_static1 PRIMARY 4   T1.col1 1   Using where
```

On a different matter, here is something VERY strange.  The following version of the query WITH `ORDER BY` completes in just **0.2 seconds**:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN T1 . * , T2 . * 
FROM Table3 AS T3
JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T3.col1 = T2.col1
AND (
T2.col4 = 'Y'
OR T2.col5 = 'Y'
)
JOIN Table1 AS T1 ON T3.col1 = T1.col1
AND 3963.191 * ACOS( (
SIN( PI( ) * - 87.8819594 /180 ) * SIN( PI( ) * T3.latitude /180 ) ) + ( COS( PI( ) * - 87.8819594 /180 ) * COS( PI( ) * T3.latitude /180 ) * COS( PI( ) * T3.longitude /180 - PI( )* 37.1092162 /180 ) )
) <=10
WHERE T1.col2 LIKE 'A'
AND (
T1.col3 LIKE 'X'
OR T1.col3 LIKE 'X-Y'
)
AND T1.col1 != '1'
ORDER BY T1.col6 DESC
```

Basically, this version of the query does a `FROM Table3 AS T3` and `JOIN` tables 1 and 2 whereas the original query does `FROM Table1 AS T1` and `JOIN` tables 2 and 3.

Here is the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` for the query above:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  T3  ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    141923  100 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  T2  eq_ref  PRIMARY,col4,col5,CompositeIndex1   PRIMARY 4   T3.col1 1   100 Using where
1   SIMPLE  T1  eq_ref  PRIMARY,col2,col3,col1,CompositeIndex1,idx01    PRIMARY 4   T2.col1 1   100 Using where
```

Notice how this query actually does BOTH a `filesort` and a `temporary` vs. just a `filesort` on the original and new queries from Ivan.  **How can that be 10x faster?**

Even stranger, switching the order of the `JOIN` does not seem to improve neither the original query nor the newer queries from Ivan.    **Why is that?**

Comment: +1 for the effort and the information on what you've tried

Comment: Is an index really needed for ALL columns?  Having an index on everything can have a negative affect on performance.  I would only put one on the columns that you use.

Comment: Check this answer for improving the performance of an ORDER BY query, especially the part about tweaking the values of the `sort_buffer_size` and `read_rnd_buffer_size` variables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935391/getting-rid-of-using-temporary-using-filesort

Comment: You have not tried creating the index with descending value storage. You just simply need to add `DESC` after the column name in the index.

Comment: The negative effect of overindexing should only be on the writing of rows, not reading them.

Comment: @njk unfortunately, mysql will let you create an index with the DESC modifier, but it silently builds an ASC index.

Comment: @bobwienholt I don't understand your comment. Why is that unfortunate?

Comment: @njk Because MySQL doesn't support DESC indexes.  It would be really nice if it did.  From the MySQL manual: "An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I finally found the solution to my question.

If we put the entire WHERE clause -- **except** the part that calculates the radius -- outside the original query, then we get a very fast query that does **not** use `temporary` like changing the order of the `JOIN` does:

```
SELECT * FROM
{
    SELECT
        col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
    FROM 
        Table1 AS table1 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Table2 AS table2 
    USING 
        (col1)
    LEFT JOIN 
        Table3 as table3 
    USING 
        (col1) 
    WHERE 
        3963.191 * 
        ACOS(
        (SIN(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * SIN(PI() * table3.latitude / 180)) 
        +
        (COS(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * COS(PI() * table3.latitude / 180) * COS(PI() * table3.longitude / 180 - PI() * 37.1092162 / 180))
        ) <= 10 
) AS sub
WHERE
    col1 != '1' 
AND 
    col2 LIKE 'A' 
AND 
    (col3 LIKE 'X' OR col3 LIKE 'X-Y') 
AND 
    (col4 = 'Y' OR col5 = 'Y') 
ORDER BY 
    col6 DESC
```

Essentially, this query first gets the `JOIN` results of all 3 tables based on the radius, and only then applies the rest of the filters to get the results we need.  This version of the query returns the **exact** same results as my original query, yet executes in just **0.2 seconds** vs. over **3 seconds** for my original query.

Here is the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` for it:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    43  100 Using where; Using filesort
2   DERIVED T3  ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    143153  100 Using where
2   DERIVED users   eq_ref  PRIMARY,col1,idx01  PRIMARY 4   T3.col1 1   100 
2   DERIVED userProfile eq_ref  PRIMARY,CompositeIndex1 PRIMARY 4   users.col1  1   100
```

I wanted to thank [Ivan Buttinoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564405/ivan-buttinoni) for his excellent work on this.  He found several clever ways of making this query even faster.

**Moral of the Story:**  it's not just the `ORDER BY` clause that can be made faster by [putting it outside the main query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884661/slow-query-when-using-order-by), you can also get a faster query by placing part of the WHERE clause outside it as well in situations such as this one.

Comment: Sometimes the main goal (quickest query) is more important than the way to reach that goal. In this case the "Gordian Knot" is the mysql optimizer and not the data. Even the @RolandoMySQLDBA spit the query to "drive" the optimizer. This query reminds me once with "FROM TABLE3"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Ivan!  Yes, it's somewhat similar to the thinking in the `FROM Table3` solution, but unlike that solution, this one does NOT use `Temporary` (see `EXPLAIN`).  Based on the `EXPLAIN`, do you think this query will have an "exponential decrease of performance" like the `FROM Table3` solution?

Comment: In theory, yes, and you've the data, so you can verify it simply increasing the radius of the search.

Comment: Ivan, are you saying this is NOT a good solution since it will have an exponential decrease in performance even though it does not use `Temporary'?  How can I verify it by increasing the radius of the search (I'm not sure how to do that)?  I thought this was the perfect solution, but it seems from what you are saying that this is not the case because of the exponential decrease of performance... :(

Comment: First of all the radius: instead **3963.191 * ACOS( ... ) <= 10** try **3963.191 * ACOS( ... ) <= 1000**, you will search within 1000 miles of radius

Comment: Second, it **could be** a bad solution if performances will **really** decrease in live environment. Your solution seem good, even if it don't use any index. A stress test can give you a good and definitive evaluation.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  I think the best JOIN solution then is this one BUT with your square formula to make it even faster.  Thanks again for all your help, Ivan!  I've awarded you the bounty! :)

Answer (score 5):

Well,
I suggest you some restyles of the query:

1. put in where conditions not join related, see 2nd query:

   AND ( T1.col3 LIKE 'X' OR T1.col3 LIKE 'X-Y')
2. avoid **OR** use IN
3. avoid **like** use **=**

   AND T1.col3 IN ( 'X' , 'X-Y')
4. avoid computation in where

create some new columns to store:

```
SIN(PI() * T3.latitude / 180)
COS(PI() * table3.longitude / 180 - PI() * 37.1092162 / 180)
COS(PI() * T3.latitude / 180)
```

5. pre-evaluate

   SIN(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180)
   COS(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180)
6. if all these "tricks" can't avoid *file-sort* force the indexes

[mysql query index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html)

FURTHER ADD

in order to remove:

```
( T2.Col4 = 'Y' OR T2.Col5 = 'Y' )
```

in this case you can't use **IN**, so create a new column that is the result of this expression.

```
alter table table2 add static1 bit default 0;
alter table add index idx_static1(static1);
update table2 t2 set static1=1 where ( T2.Col4 = 'Y' OR T2.Col5 = 'Y' );

alter table table3 add static2 float(18,16) default 0;
update table3 set static2=SIN(PI() * T3.latitude / 180) where 1

alter table table3 add static3 float(18,16) default 0;
update table3 set static3 = COS(PI() * T3.latitude / 180) * COS(PI() * table3.longitude / 180 - PI() * 37.1092162 / 180)   where 1
```

If **table1.col2** has few values

```
alter table table1 change col2 col2 enum('A','B','C');
```

If **table1.col3** has few values

```
alter table table1 change col3 col3 enum('X','Y','X-Y');
```

Create an unique index for *all* the columns involved in where
alter table add index idx01 (col1,col2,col3)

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      T1.*, 
      T2.*
   FROM 
      Table1 AS T1
         JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
         JOIN Table3 as T3 ON T1.Col1 = T3.Col1

   WHERE static1=1 AND
          T1.Col2 = 'A'
      AND T1.col3 IN ( 'X', 'X-Y') 
      AND T1.Col1 != 1
      AND ACOS(  
                 ( 
                   $usersLatitude_sin_pi_fract180  * t3.static2 
                   + $usersLatitude_cos_pi_fract180  * t3.static3 
                 )   
               ) <= 0,00252321929476 -- this's 10/3963.191
      ORDER BY T1.Col6
```

Your comment suggest me that you've a different collation in the query (col1 is latin1_swedish and col2 is utf8) or your connection use a different collation (your connection is utf-8 and you query a latin1_german column) so when you query:

```
t1.col2 = 'A'
```

Mysql has to convert from utf-8 to latin1 each value.

See also the [collate section](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collate.html) of mysql documentation.

A quick way is to convert all (column, table, server, connection, client) to the same collation singel byte will be better if you don't need utf-8.

Be carefull to my type error or syntax error I could done.

**FURTHER ADD 2**

I recreated the tables on a test DB and I fixed this columns:
t1.col2, t2.col3 **must not nullable**, t1.col1 is primary and can't be null.

Index "t1.CompositeIndex1" should index only: col2, col3, col1; Index an "order by" column is unusefull or worst.

I create static1 and I create an index on t2.col1 and t2.static1 but with my 6 rows in DB is not used (see explain later). t2.static1 must not nullable too.

I also adapt the query to the collate of the columns:

```
SELECT  T1.*, T2.* 
FROM Table1 AS T1
         JOIN Table2 AS T2   ON ( T1.Col1 = T2.Col1   )
         JOIN Table3 as T3 ON T1.Col1 = T3.Col1
   WHERE  
         (  T1.Col2 =    'A'   collate utf8_bin  AND T1.col3 IN  ( 'X' collate utf8_bin , 'X-Y'  collate utf8_bin )   AND T1.Col1 != 1 )
and T2.static1=1
      AND ACOS(  (   2.3  * T3.static2  + 1.2 * T3.static3  ) ) <= 0.00252321929476 
      ORDER BY T1.Col6
```

Here follows the explain extended

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------+-----------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                     | key             | key_len | ref            | rows | filtered | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------+-----------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T1    | ref    | PRIMARY,col2,col3,CompositeIndex1 | CompositeIndex1 | 1       | const          |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,CompositeIndex1           | PRIMARY         | 4       | testdb.T1.col1 |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | T3    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY         | 4       | testdb.T1.col1 |    1 |   100.00 | Using where                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------+-----------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+-----------------------------+
```

Is it the **same** for the colums: select_type, table, type, key, ref, filtered, Extra?

My optimization goals are:
- fit the where conditions in few index
- avoid calculations
- avoid collate conversion
- avoid OR
- avoid NULLs in where condition

Now the bad news
It seems that in the tables you've ~140K records, and query using order can imply the using of the filesort approach if the query involve a lot of rows, so the final answer can be increase the memsort buffer as suggest by @mavroprovato.

**FURTHER ADD 3**

To evauate the adequacy of **key_buffer_size** see on [http://dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20083/whats-the-formula-for-calculating-key-efficiency-key-buffer-used-and-query-ca)

**FURTHER ADD 4**

I think that only someone in Oracle can say exactly what happens, but I've my idea.

I think that this query is peculiar:

1. all tables (t1,t2,t3) are joinded by primary key
2. other conditions depends only by calcs (t3.colX )
3. some conditions depend only by index (t1.colX )

Because of 1 from_table_rows >= join1_table_rows >= join2_table_rows, so less rows return the from table quickest will be the 2 other JOINs

The optimizer to evaluate the effort will calc a similar equation:

```
effort = num_rows*key_size/index_cardinality
```

(index_cardinality is show by phpmyadmin next each index)

Because of 2 effort is >= num_rows

**My query** 
because of 3 the the table1 (from table) returns 92333 rows, table3 (join1_table) reduce to 1(!) row, table2 keep 1 row (effort ~ 3).

**Your query**
because of 2 you should have an effort = 140000, but luckylly for you the calc return just 1 results so your query is extremelly quick

**Demostration**

In your query changing from "<=10" (in join condition) to "<=1000" or more you will see a exponential decrease of performances.

In my query changing from "<=10" (in join condition) to "<=1000" or more you will see a linear/logarithm decrease of performances.

**FURTHER ADD 5**

answer to the question: is sort-buffer-size too big?

standing on article, yes, try some tune, may be you can solve the problem

answer to the question: is impossible to do a quick query?

IMHO no, it's possible (even if sort-buffer-size don't resolve).

My idea is quite simple, and it can resume in this mot: "cirlce is nice but square is better".

At the moment the biggest cardinality is on the coordinates in table3, but because of formula no index is applicable. So, instead of search all points inside a radius, you can search all points inside a "square"

```
FROM table3
...
WHERE (t3.latitude-0.15) < $usersLatitude AND  $usersLatitude < t3.latitude+0.15  
AND t3.longitue - 0.15 < $usersLongitude AND   $usersLongitude < t3.longitue + 0.15
```

so you can create an index in (t3.latitude,t3.longitue).

*0.15* degrees should be 10 miles. 
Of course you should fix the calcs near the day-change meridian and next to the poles

If you need strictly a radius you can re-join table3 with the radius formula (see example below) or **if possible** carry out(/elaborate) the formula until you can compare directly values with columns.

```
FROM table3 t3
JOIN table3 t3bis ON t3.id=t3bis.id
...
WHERE (t3.latitude-0.15) < $usersLatitude AND  $usersLatitude < t3.latitude+0.15  
AND t3.longitue - 0.15 < $usersLongitude AND   $usersLongitude < t3.longitue + 0.15
AND 
3963.191 
* ACOS(  (SIN(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * SIN(PI() * t3bis.latitude / 180)) 
+ (  COS(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * COS(PI() * t3bis.latitude / 180) 
* COS(PI() * t3bis.longitude / 180 - PI() * 37.1092162 / 180)
)   
) <= 10
```

**FURTHER ADD 6**

topic: compiled functions do it better

**use of RADIANS() function**

```
degree * PI / 180 == radians(degree)
```

**Use of GIS extension of mysql**

See this [article about MySql GIS extension](http://www.lenzg.net/archives/220-New-UDF-for-MySQL-5.1-provides-GIS-functions-distance_sphere-and-distance_spheroid.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to re-style my entire query based on your suggestions.  Could you please post a version of my query that fulfills all your suggested styles?  Also, regarding #3, using `=` in place of `LIKE` in this query slows it down by a factor of **10**, but I don't know why.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details!  I will try EVERYTHING you suggested and report back.

Comment: Ivan, I followed your suggestions and executed your query, but it did not improve the performance.  Specifically, I created new columns in `Table3` to store `SIN(PI() * T3.latitude / 180)`, `COS(PI() * table3.longitude / 180 - PI() * 37.1092162 / 180)`, `COS(PI() * T3.latitude / 180)`, I pre-evaluated `$usersLatitude_sin_pi_fract180` and `$usersLatitude_cos_pi_fract180`, changed col2 and col3 to `enum`, [cont...]

Comment: can you post the create table SQL? (of all tables)

Comment: I actually left out `( T2.Col4 = 'Y' OR T2.Col5 = 'Y' )` from the query to avoid using `static1` for now, I created an index for `static2` and `static3`, and every other column already had an index, including a composite index in `Table1` for `col1, col2, col3`. [cont...]

Comment: `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` still shows `Using filesort`.  What's interesting is that if instead of `FROM 
      Table1 AS T1
         JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1
         JOIN Table3 as T3 ON T1.Col1 = T3.Col1` I do `FROM 
      Table3 AS T3
         JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T3.Col1 = T2.Col1
         JOIN Table1 as T1 ON T3.Col1 = T1.Col1`, it executes very fast. [cont...]

Comment: You mentioned something about forcing the index, so maybe I should try that next?

Comment: What do you mean by "can you post the create table SQL?"  How can I do that?  Thanks.

Comment: show create table table1; show create table table2; show create table table3;

Comment: Thanks, I will do that now and post it.  In the meantime, do any of my other comments above indicate any hints as to what the problem is?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have Skype, but I don't mind continuing to comment here or via SO chat.  I have added the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to my post, as requested.  Please let me know what you see and what we should try next.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, replicating on local DB missing col6 on table1

Comment: Sorry, just added `col6` on `Table1` in post.

Comment: Ivan, incredible work, thank you!  A few questions:  **1)** why must some columns not be nullable?  **2)** How can I estimate the **memory buffer** size I need? **3)**  What do you mean by "*Is it the same for the colums: select_type, table, type, key, ref, filtered, Extra?*" ? **4)**  As mentioned above, if instead of `FROM Table1 AS T1 JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 JOIN Table3 as T3 ON T1.Col1 = T3.Col1` I do `FROM Table3 AS T3 JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T3.Col1 = T2.Col1 JOIN Table1 as T1 ON T3.Col1 = T1.Col1`, it executes very fast, so should I maybe do that instead? What's the diff?

Comment: 1) IMO because mysql knows the query will generate a deterministic "evaluation" before evaluate the index
2) I'll add in answer
3) I was asking a confirm that your "explain extended" gave same results on these columns
4) It will change the order of evaluation of the conditions/index; an efficient optimizer could change this order. Mysql optimizer is efficient? Sometimes no.

PS
remember to tag my answer! ;)

Comment: Regarding your comment answer **4)**, I'm not sure I understand.  Should I do `FROM Table3 AS T3` and `JOIN` tables 1 and 2 considering that executes in **0.2 seconds** compared to over **3 seconds** for the original query that does `FROM Table1 AS T1` and `JOIN` tables 2 and 3?

Comment: Interesting. Can you add to the question the "explain extended" of the 2 queries? Have you seen the "FURTHER ADD 3" too?

Comment: Ivan, my `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` of the latest version of your query is slightly different to yours. I've included it under **EDIT2** in my post. Also, I've included a version of the query with `ORDER BY` that executes in **0.2 s** by just switching the order of the `JOIN`, and have also included the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` for it. Strangely, it does BOTH a `filesort` AND `temporary`, yet it's 10x faster. Last but not least, I included the configuration file for my MySQL in case that uncovers any inefficiencies. Please have a look at everything in **EDIT 2** and advise regarding the next step. Thanks!

Comment: Ivan, thanks for your theory in **Further Add 4**.  That makes sense, but it also means that even my "fast" query using `FROM Table3` isn't a "solution" since it will have an exponential decrease in performance as the site grows.  Have you had a chance to look through the MySQL Configuration variables that I also posted in **EDIT 2**?  Maybe the reason my query is slow is hidden somewhere there?  Surely, there has to be a way to make this query fast, or is that **impossible**?

Comment: Do you mean **Further Add 4**?  That's what I was referring to in my last comment above.  Please let me know.

Comment: No **Further Add 5**, still writing :D

Comment: OK, no problem.  Thanks again and I look forward to reading it! :)

Comment: Ivan, thanks for the **Further Add 5**.  However, I have good news!  I found the solution to making the original query faster, and it is a lot simpler than we first imagined.  I have added it as a solution to my question.  Please read it and let me know what you think in the comments.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ivan, did you get a chance to read my comment above and look at my solution?  Please let me know as I'd be very interested in hearing your opinion about it.  Thanks!

Comment: last 2 day I was very busy, I read it quickly. Hope this evening.

Comment: Ivan, I just wanted to follow up with you regarding my solution.  Please let me know when you have time.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Programmer (seem to me Tron:), I comment your query, but I like to know about my "square" approach. Se my (little) add to my answer about the spatial calculation

Comment: Hi Ivan, I tried the "square" approach but it did not make the query fast.  The problem seems to be with how MySQL is JOINing the tables, and not with the speed of the formula for distance.  In fact, if I run a query *just* in Table3 with no JOINs, even the original "long" formula is fast.  That said, you have provided several solutions to make the formula even faster, which is very helpful.  Your FURTHER ADD 6, is interesting, and I will have to explore the GIS extension to see if I can improve the query even more.  But how would I apply the `RADIANS()` function in my query?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, the goal of the square approach, is to move from a CPU approach to an index approach. Anout radians: you can express **COS(PI() * t3bis.latitude / 180)** as **COS(RADIANS(t3bis.latitude))**

Comment: Thanks for all your incredibel help, Ivan!  Bounty awarded!  Grazie mille!

Answer (score 1):

Try the first query:

```
...
FROM 
    Table1 AS table1 USE INDEX (col6)
LEFT JOIN 
    Table2 AS table2   
...
```

Comment: That did not improve the performance of the query.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of table1.col6?
What its field diameter (max value length)?

BTW pre-calculate values, which do not depend on field values, like Ivan Buttinoni suggested. It will not help with ordering, but will make query faster

Comment: table1.col6 is of type `int(11)`.  All the data types appear below the query above.  Let me know if you have any other ideas!

Comment: I would try to place col6 on the first place and "ORDER BY 1 DESC".

Answer (score 0):

There are three(3) things I see you can do:

1) Refactor the query

2) Apply the ORDER BY on Table1 earlier in the Query

3) Index Table1 to support refactor

Perhaps this...

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD INDEX col2_col6_ndx (col2,col6);
SELECT
    table1.*, 
    table2.*
FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM Table1
        WHERE col2='A' AND 
        ORDER BY col6 DESC
    ) AS table1
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT * FROM Table2
        WHERE (col4='Y' OR col5='Y')
    ) AS table2 
USING 
    (col1)
LEFT JOIN 
    Table3 as table3 
USING 
    (col1) 
WHERE 
    table1.col1 != '1' AND
    table1.col3 IN ('X','X-Y') AND
    3963.191 * 
    ACOS(
    (SIN(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * SIN(PI() * table3.latitude / 180)) 
    +
    (COS(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * COS(PI() * table3.latitude / 180) * COS(PI() * table3.longitude / 180 - PI() * 37.1092162 / 180))
    ) <= 10 
;
```

Here is another variation that attempts to refactor the query so that only keys are gathered first (creating much smaller temp tables) and then JOINS are applied:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD INDEX col2613_ndx (col2,col6,col1,col3);
ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD INDEX col4_col1_ndx (col4,col1);
ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD INDEX col5_col1_ndx (col5,col1);
SELECT 
    table1.*, 
    table2.*
FROM
(
    SELECT table1.col1,table3.latitude,table3.longitude 
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT col1 FROM Table1 WHERE col2='A' AND
            AND col3 IN ('X','X-Y') ORDER BY col6 DESC
        ) AS table1
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT col1 FROM Table2 WHERE col4='Y' UNION
            SELECT col1 FROM Table2 WHERE col5='Y'
        ) AS table2 
    USING (col1)
    LEFT JOIN Table3 as table3 USING (col1)
) col1_keys
LEFT JOIN Table1 table1 USING (col1)
LEFT JOIN Table2 table2 USING (col1)
WHERE 
    3963.191 * 
    ACOS(
    (SIN(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * SIN(PI() * col1_keys.latitude / 180)) 
    +
    (COS(PI() * $usersLatitude / 180) * COS(PI() * col1_keys.latitude / 180)
    * COS(PI() * col1_keys.longitude / 180 - PI() * 37.1092162 / 180))
    ) <= 10 
;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Interesting solution, I will try it out.  Is the `col2` condition (which is in `Table1`) meant to be put in the JOIN of `Table2`?  Likewise, is the `col3` condition (which is also in `Table1) meant to be put in the JOIN of `Table3`?  Lastly, how does this solution compare to the solution I posted?  Pros/Cons?  Please let me know and thanks again!

Comment: I updated my answer. The reason for my suggestions was based on a post I answered May 16, 2011 : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6023217/491757. I suggested rewiring the query so that any table-specific WHERE clauses were addressed before any JOIN took place. In that post, the EXPLAIN PLAN was actually worse than the original, but was not only faster than other queries posted but was faster as the dataset grew.

Comment: I honestly do not know if my query would be faster or not, except to try it. As for far your answer goes, I did not notice you even answered it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'm still confused, however, because you are using `col3` from `Table1` in the JOIN of `Table3`, and in `Table3` you have `SELECT col1, latitude,`.  Could you please review my original query again and make sure you have the correct version of your solution?  I would love to try it out, but I just want to make sure we get it right so it produces the exact same results (but hopefully faster).  Thanks!

Comment: That what I get for reading the question at 4:00 AM. I didn't properly read the CREATE TABLE statements and put the columns into the proper table contexts.

Comment: No problem, that happens to the best of us.  When you're feeling up for it, please review it carefully and fix it so it's the equivalent of my original query, and I'll give it a shot and report back.  Thanks again! :)

Comment: Rolando, I tried your query EXACTLY as you have it written above, after adding the indexes you also mentioned above, but it was incredibly slow and took over a minute and brought my server to a standstill so I had to restart MySQL.  Any other ideas?  What about my solution, do you see any problems with it?  Please let me know.  Thanks!