# mysql explain result interpretation

Tags: mysql

The query below does exactly what I expect it to do, is intuitive and doesn't generate intermediary tables. The downside is that it takes a long time to complete.

What I'll do in such cases is break the query in steps and create those intermediary tables & indexes. This time around I'd like to get a better handle on the hints provided by explain, and would appreciate any pointers: what obvious optimization steps am I missing in the query below?

Following the advice in [MySQL query optimization and EXPLAIN for a noob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934614/mysql-query-optimization-and-explain-for-a-noob) I've created indices on `order_number` , `order_type` and `item` in `orders_raw`. It's unclear however how these would carry over character processing/regexes.

[image: Output of EXPLAIN]

```
SELECT bundle_headers.order_number , bundle_headers.title , digital_subs.subscription_id , 1 as bundle_component
from
(
  select order_number , substring( item , 1 , 3 ) as title , quantity from orders_raw
  where order_type in (4,6)                      
) bundle_headers
inner join
(
  select order_number , subscription_id , item as title , quantity from orders_raw
  where order_type = 0 and length( item ) = 4    
) digital_subs
on bundle_headers.order_number = digital_subs.order_number and
   digital_subs.title regexp concat( '.*' , bundle_headers.title , '.*' ) and
   bundle_headers.quantity = digital_subs.quantity

UNION


SELECT bundle_headers.order_number , bundle_headers.title , print_subs.subscription_id , 1 as bundle_component
from
(
  select order_number , substring( item , 1 , 3 ) as title , quantity from orders_raw
  where order_type in (4,6)                      
) bundle_headers
inner join
(
  select order_number , subscription_id , item as title , quantity from orders_raw
  where order_type = 0 and length( item ) = 3    
) print_subs
on bundle_headers.order_number = print_subs.order_number and
   print_subs.title regexp concat( '.*' , bundle_headers.title , '.*' ) and
   bundle_headers.quantity = print_subs.quantity;
```

EDIT, @tin tran: I've yet to rigorously time both the query above and your query (after a couple corrections, copied below) starting out on an idle machine. I did submit it, and didn't see an obvious reduction in run time.

```
 SELECT bundle_headers.order_number,
   substring(bundle_headers.item,1,3) as title,
   subs.subscription_id,
   1 as bundle_component
 FROM orders_raw bundle_headers
 INNER JOIN orders_raw subs ON (bundle_headers.order_number = subs.order_number)
 WHERE (bundle_headers.order_type = 4 OR bundle_headers.order_type = 6)
   AND subs.order_type = 0
   AND bundle_headers.quantity = subs.quantity
   AND subs.item LIKE CONCAT('%',substring(bundle_headers.item,1,3),'%')
   AND (length(subs.item) = 4 OR length(subs.item) = 3)
```

Comment: Although your question is specifically about `EXPLAIN`, I would recommend you create temp tables and use them instead of the subqueries... I've used that approach and it speeds things up. Of course, you need to create the appropriate indexes for the temp tables: `drop table if exists temp_myTable; create temporary table temp_myTable select ... ; alter table temp_myTable add index idx_anIndex(aField), ...; `

Comment: @Barranka - temp tables instead of subqueries? Faster?? I hear this first time...

Comment: @Tomas believe it or not... I've faced this sort of task many times, and in most cases, creating intermediate temp tables makes things faster than subqueries. Of course, they must be created carefully and they need to be properly indexed.

Comment: I've ended up splitting the query, as I usually do, inserting indexes as I go along. Pedestrian, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

please try this query see if it produces the same result. And if it's any faster

```
SELECT bundle_headers.order_number,substring(bundle_headers.title,1,3) as title,subs.subscription_id,1 as bundle_component
FROM order_type bundle_headers
INNER JOIN orders_raw subs ON (bundle_headers.order_number = subs.order_number)
WHERE (bundle_headers.order_type = 4 OR bundle_headers.order_type = 6)
  AND subs.order_type = 0
  AND bundle_headers.quantity = subs.quantity
  AND subs.title LIKE CONCAT('%',substring(bundle_headers.title,1,3),'%')
  AND (length(subs.item) = 4 OR length(subs.item) = 3)
```